# How to set up dnsmasq for static ip-address name resolving on OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt, dnsmasq

In my network I have a range for hosts with dynamic ip-adresses which the dhcp-server in `OpenWrt` serves.

I also have some hosts in the network with fixed ip-adresses.

Where can I set them up in `dnsmasq` so that dns-requests to their hostnames can be resolved by the clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a bit more I believe it's enough to add the static hosts to `/etc/hosts`. I will confirm after I could test it.

Edit: It works.